# How do I find out the DOM node when select text in a browser’s editable content window using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, selection, element, parent

I want to get parentElement when I select some text in iframe.

```
iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
function getParentElement(){
 var sel=iframe.contentDocument.getselection();
 return sel.parentElement()
}
getParentElement();
```

when I run this code it show  `Error:" TypeError: iframe.contentDocument.getSelection().parentElement is not a function { message="iframe.contentDocument....ement is not a function",  more...}"`

Please give me a help!

Comment: iframe.contentDocument.get**S**election(); returns a string and not the element, so this cannot be used to get parent element. And parentElement is not a function but a property, so you should use it without parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Selection object (returned by getSelection()) has no method named *parentElement()*. This will give you the parent:

```
getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode
```

See Mozilla's [DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection).